# Updating Database: Keeping the original data if the TextField is blank onPressed

Tags: flutter

I've created a form that allows me to update my database. However, if `updateAddCash` is pressed when the form is blank it updates the database to `""` as well.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TestState createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  TextEditingController updateNameController;
  String _displayValue = "";
  // TextEditingController updateAmountController;
  Future<List<AddCash>> future;

  @override
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    updateNameController = TextEditingController();

    future = RepositoryServiceAddCash.getAllAddCash();
  }

  void dispose() {
    updateNameController.dispose();

    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          //Text Field to update data
          TextField(
            controller: updateNameController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              border: InputBorder.none,
              hintText: '${addCash.name}',
            ),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Update"),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
              return updateAddCash(addCash);
            },
            //Shows data from Database
            Text(
          '${addCash.name}',
        ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  updateAddCash(AddCash addCash) async {
    String name = updateNameController.text;

    addCash.name = name;

    await RepositoryServiceAddCash.updateAddCash(addCash);
    setState(() {
      _displayValue = name;
      future = RepositoryServiceAddCash.getAllAddCash();
    });

    if (_displayValue.isEmpty) {
      //KEEP OLD VALUE
      addCash.name
    } else {
      //ADD NEW VALUE
    }
  }
}
```

How would I keep the original value if the form is blank?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "keeping the original data". I tried to come up for a solution for you but I do not understand what you are trying to achieve when the display value is empty. Can you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 0):

using future in the initState add a getter function and fetch all the you need and save it in a variable then if textfield1 is empty then pass the value from the getter as your textfield's value